# In laravel if else not switching perfectly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to displaying image in view with if else condition.

My code displaying image but height and width remains 70 for all images.

```
@if (File::exists($view_and_download->digital_signature_image == 'Digital-right-mark.png'))
    <div class="digital_right_png" >
       <img height="70" width="70" src="CERTIFICATE_AND_HARD_COPY_FILE/{{$view_and_download->digital_signature_image}}">
    </div>
@else 
    <div class="digital_signature_png" >
       <img height="30" width="100" src="CERTIFICATE_AND_HARD_COPY_FILE/{{$view_and_download->digital_signature_image}}">
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This :

`$view_and_download->digital_signature_image == 'Digital-right-mark.png'`

will give you `true` or `false`

So what will happen will be

`File::exists(true)` or `File::exists(false)` 
So in your @if for either case will be false and should always go to else block.

What you should actually be doing is comparing the file name before File::exists condition like:

```
 @if ($view_and_download->digital_signature_image == 'Digital-right-mark.png' && File::exists('CERTIFICATE_AND_HARD_COPY_FILE/'.$view_and_download->digital_signature_image))

    <div class="digital_right_png" ><img  height="70" width="70"   src="CERTIFICATE_AND_HARD_COPY_FILE/{{$view_and_download->digital_signature_image}}"> </div>

@else

    <div class="digital_signature_png" ><img  height="30" width="100"   src="CERTIFICATE_AND_HARD_COPY_FILE/{{$view_and_download->digital_signature_image}}"> </div>

@endif
```

Note: Don't forget to add file path to File::exists() too. `CERTIFICATE_AND_HARD_COPY_FILE` replace this with the file path.

Comment: are you sure file exists in the defined path and the name of the file is `Digital-right-mark.png`? Also, `$view_and_download->digital_signature_image` will have value of `Digital-right-mark.png` at sometimes? Otherwise it will go to else block only

Comment: well then only you can check is that if `File::exists()` and `$view_and_download->digital_signature_image == 'Digital-right-mark.png'` will return true or not seperately by using `dd()`. Are you perfoming this in loop?

Comment: it showing error #message: "Use of undefined constant CERTIFICATE_AND_HARD_COPY_FILE - assumed 'CERTIFICATE_AND_HARD_COPY_FILE' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"

Comment: `CERTIFICATE_AND_HARD_COPY_FILE` should be the file path I just used it as a reference. If it is actually the directory name then use it as string like `File::exists('CERTIFICATE_AND_HARD_COPY_FILE/'.$view_and_download->digital_signature_image)`
`